# How do you take the derivative of a trace of matrix kroenecker products?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, trace, kronecker-product

Let $M \in \mathbb{C}^{vr \times vc}$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{v \times v}$, where $P \succ 0 $

then,

$F = Tr(M (P^{-1} \otimes I_{c}) M^H (P \otimes I_{r}))$,

where,

$I_{r} \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ and $I_{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{c \times c}$ are identity matrices, respectively. $Tr()$ is the trace of a matrix.

We want to compute $\frac{dF}{dP}$. I know that we can decompose $M = \sum_i B_i \otimes E_i$ and then use the properties of a Kronecker product to distribute the trace, which would yield $F = \sum_{ij} Tr(B_iP^{-1}B_j^HP) Tr(E_i E_j^H)$ and then take the derivative $\frac{dF}{dP}$, which is easily done.

However, is it possible to compute $\frac{dF}{dP}$ without the decomposition of $M$?

The end goal is to solve $\frac{dF}{dP} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\l{j}
\def\I{I_{\tt1}}
\def\C{C^{-\tt1}}
\def\Ct{C^{-T}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}\def\o{{\,\big[\tt1}\big]\,}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Use a colon to denote the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent
ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A = \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Use $\{e_\l,\;\e_k\}$ to denote the euclidean basis vectors
for $\{\bbR{r},\bbR{c}\}$ respectively, which can be used to write identity matrices as rank-one sums
$$\eqalign{
\I &= \o \\
I_r &= \sum_{\l=1}^r e_\l e_\l^T = \sum_{\l=1}^r e_\l\,I_1\,e_\l^T \\
I_c &= \sum_{k=1}^c \e_k \e_k^T  = \sum_{k=1}^c \e_k \,I_1\,\e_k^T \\
}$$
The above can be used to rearrange the trace of a Kronecker product
$$\eqalign{
\trace{A^T\LR{P\otimes I_c}}
 &= A:\LR{P\otimes I_c} \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^c A:\LR{P\otimes \e_k\I\e_k^T}  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^c A
 :\LR{\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}\LR{P\otimes\I}\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}^T} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^c A
 :\LR{\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}\,P\,\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}^T} \\
&= \LR{\sum_{k=1}^c \LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}^TA\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}}:P \\
}$$

---

For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
C &= P\otimes I_c &\qiq dC = dP\otimes I_c \\
R &= P\otimes I_r &\qiq dR = dP\otimes I_r \\
A &= \LR{\C M^HRM\C}^T \\
B &= \LR{M\C M^H}^T \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
F &= M^T:\LR{\C M^HR} \\
dF &= M^T:\LR{\C M^H\,dR} + M^T:\LR{d\C\,M^HR} \\
  &= \LR{M^*\Ct M^T}:{dR} - {M^T}:\LR{\C\,dC\,\C M^HR} \\
  &= \LR{M^*\Ct M^T}:{dR} - \LR{\Ct M^TR^TM^*\Ct}:{dC} \\
  &= B:\LR{dP\otimes I_r} - A:\LR{dP\otimes I_c} \\
&= \LR{\sum_{\l=1}^r \LR{I_v\otimes e_\l}^TB\LR{I_v\otimes e_\l}}:dP
 - \LR{\sum_{k=1}^c \LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}^TA\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}}:dP \\
\grad{F}{P}
&= \LR{\sum_{\l=1}^r \LR{I_v\otimes e_\l}^TB\LR{I_v\otimes e_\l}} 
 - \LR{\sum_{k=1}^c \LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}^TA\LR{I_v\otimes\e_k}} \\
}$$
So that's the gradient expression if you decompose $I_c$ and $I_r$ rather than $M$.

In either case, a closed-form solution of the *zero-gradient* condition is impossible. However, since you have an exact formula for the gradient of $F$, it would be a simple exercise to use your favorite gradient-based solver (e.g. Conjugate Gradients, Barzilai-Borwein, etc) to numerically calculate the optimal value(s) of $P$.